# How do you use EmberData models with select2 view?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, jquery-select2

I want to use an EmberData model together with a select2 component/view.

I started with the gist https://gist.github.com/aboma/5737133 of @buuda (referenced in [dynamically setting selected option in ember.select which uses select2 lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18446585/dynamically-setting-selected-option-in-ember-select-which-uses-select2-lib)).

But I have no idea how to connect the select2 model with EmberData models.

By giving an initSelection function in the select2 options you get a hook to initialize an existing initial selection. When I call `App.MyModel.find(id)` in my `initSelection()` then I get a *promise*. Is it a good idea to resolve the promise in the initSelection function?

Another option you can give to select2 is the `query` function. select2 uses this function to populate the list of selectable options. How can I connect the results of `App.MyModel.find({...})` to the select2 `query()` function?